# Can I create a Web-to-Lead field for Custom Objects?

Tags: custom-object, web2lead

I've created a Custom field on my lead called 'Campus' with datatype Lookup(Campus). Where Campus is a custom object.

I would like to have a Web-to-lead form create a new lead and set the correct campus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not appear to work without a little bit of a workaround but there is an idea out on the idea exchange [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br6C). One user suggests using the process builder with flow to set the lookup field another alternative would be a trigger (that was what I had done in the past).

Answer (score 0):

If campus is a small predefined list with very less chance to change, in web to lead form you can display it as a dropdown of hard coded campus values(if you allow it to be a free text, users might type random values). Then map this value to a backend text field in the lead object. Finally write a trigger on Lead object to check for matching campus in campus object and populate lookup field value.